# Springboard-like menu to select other views in storyboard

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, storyboard, springboard

I use a storyboard and I want to make a springboard menu like that http://static5.businessinsider.com/image/4d657896cadcbbd948120000-590/this-is-what-badoos-iphone-app-looks-like-when-you-first-launch-it-just-one-of-many-ways-to-use-the-service-smartly-you-can-do-things-without-registering-lets-look-at-people-nearby.jpg with only one page and nine icons.

I found the library Three20 but it is complex and I have problems to import it to my project.

Any suggestion?

Comment: What exactly is the purpose of this springboard? Does it have to be dynamic? Do people drag things around? Can you delete stuff on it? If the answer is no for all of the questions; just place a few buttons on an empty page.. If the answer is yes on some of the questions; it's just as easy to write one yourself as it is to understand some open source framework (three20 has long passed its expiration date i.m.o).

Comment: Not dragging things or deleting, only select icon to go to another view. Any advice to do it using storyboard? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I think dragging buttons onto your view in a grid-like manner, and connecting the touch events to new views, should do the trick. Even in storyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for the people who are looking for the answer (it's hidden in the comments below the question);

*me:*

> What exactly is the purpose of this springboard? Does it have to be dynamic? Do people drag things around? Can you delete stuff on it? If the answer is no for all of the questions; just place a few buttons on an empty page.. If the answer is yes on some of the questions; it's just as easy to write one yourself as it is to understand some open source framework (three20 has long passed its expiration date i.m.o).

*Ángel Carlos del Pozo Muela:*

> Not dragging things or deleting, only select icon to go to another
>   view. Any advice to do it using storyboard? Thanks a lot.

*me*:

> I think dragging buttons onto your view in a grid-like manner, and
>   connecting the touch events to new views, should do the trick. Even in
>   storyboard.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that the old version of the Badoo app actually used three20. ;-) So I guess you're stuck with implementing that, although I wouldn't add three20 to any new project.